# How to write sql query to show reminder of task for specific time period with end date column?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am working on one application where i have one table with `company_name`,`start_date`,`end_date`. I have many companies with their respective quarters of January-March, April-June, July-September,October-December.I am attaching my sql data screenshot for your help.[image]

Now, lets say March is end_date for some companies.If you see table data ABC,XYZ and PQR are having end_date for march. So i want to display that reminders on dashboard.

> If `March` is `end_date` then it should be start to display on
>   dashboard before 1 month of `end_date` on 8th of previous month.Means
>   it will start to display on 8th of `February`. Till 7th of `May`.
>
> If `June` is `end_date` then it should be start to display on
>   dashboard before 1 month of `end_date` on 8th of previous month.Means
>   it will start to display on 8th of `May`. Till 7th of `August`.
>
> As i said it will start from previous month's 8th date till next 2
>   months and 3rd month's 7th date. How to write query for this kind of
>   scenario.

Comment: create an argument calculate the actual date before June - ending time. add a new row called 'display_start' at the date like May 1st; then, `if date between May 1st  and June 1st = show alert` . Then call the date of each day. You will have your results.

Comment: I would handle this in PHP instead of in your database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if showing the reminders is fine with '30 days before' it ends or if for legal or business requirements the reminder needs to start exactly one month before but I believe either one of these queries would be a good start to retrieve the reminders prior to the enddate (and assume not show after the end date).

The first determines if enddate is in the next 30 days:

```
-- Items with end date in next 30 days from now    
select *, DateDiff(enddate,now()) AS DaysUntilEnd
from data
where 
  DateDiff(enddate,now()) >=0 AND DateDiff(enddate,now()) < 30;
```

And the second calculates a start and end date for the reminder:

```
-- Items with notification start exactly 1 month before
select *, 
DATE_SUB(enddate, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AS NotificationStart,
enddate AS NotificationEnd
from data
where
   now() > DATE_SUB(enddate, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND
   now() <= enddate
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/468aa/11/0) you can try it out with